# how to substract upper value from lower value of mysql database table column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database table like this

```
-------------------------------------------
name     | distancefromstart  |  distance
-------------------------------------------    
AA       |    90              |
BB       |    50              |
CC       |    100             |
DD       |    10              |
```

First I want to sort this table by value of the `distancefromstart` column.
After sorting the table, the first value of `distancefromstart` should substract from second value of `distancefromstart` and second value of `distancefromstart` should substract from third value of `distancefromstart` and third value of 
`distancefromstart` should substract from forth value of `distancefromstart` and so on.

Then the new values should be added to the column called `distance` in the database.

Then the updated table should be like this:

```
name     | distancefromstart  |  distance
-------------------------------------------
AA       |    10              |  40 
BB       |    50              |  40
CC       |    90              |  10
DD       |    100             |
```

Comment: extract, loop, math, insert.

Comment: either that sounds dirty, or my flu is worse than i thought

Answer (score 0):

This will calculate the values you want:

```
select t1.name, t1.distancefromstart, t2.distancefromstart - t1.distancefromstart distance 
from t t1
  left join t t2
  on t1.distancefromstart < t2.distancefromstart
where not exists (
  select 1 
    from t t3 
    where t3.distancefromstart > t1.distancefromstart 
      and t3.distancefromstart < t2.distancefromstart
  )
order by t1.distancefromstart asc;
```

demo fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9f70/1

And if you want to update the source table, its just a matter of joining that query to the table, and updating, like so:

```
update t inner join (select t1.name, t1.distancefromstart, t2.distancefromstart - t1.distancefromstart distance 
from t t1
  left join t t2
  on t1.distancefromstart < t2.distancefromstart
where not exists (
  select 1 
    from t t3 
    where t3.distancefromstart > t1.distancefromstart 
      and t3.distancefromstart < t2.distancefromstart
  )
order by t1.distancefromstart asc) r 
on t.name = r.name and t.distancefromstart = r.distancefromstart SET t.distance = r.distance;
```

example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6819/1

Comment: @aishy glad It worked. Can you please mark the answer as accepted if it answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have "test" database, "distance" table with data like [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8724b).

Now let's taste some old plane deprecated php code:

```
<?php
// :) omg, connect to database
mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root');
mysql_select_db('test');

// extract data to array
$distances = [];
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM distances ORDER BY distancefromstart");
while ($d = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) $distances[] = $d;

// reset distances cause it may contain rubbish
mysql_query("UPDATE distances SET distance=0");

$d_prev = null; // distance before current
foreach ($distances as $d) {
    if (null !== $d_prev) {
        // distance is the diff between current distancefromstat and prev
        $distance = $d['distancefromstart'] - $d_prev['distancefromstart'];
        mysql_query('
            UPDATE distances 
            SET distance='.$distance.' 
            WHERE name="'.mysql_real_escape_string($d_prev['name']).'"'
        );
    }
    $d_prev = $d; // current will be prev on next loop
}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot. Your code is working fine..
I added a new column to the database called 'duration'
If the velocity is 50, I need to insert the duration according to the distances. I updated the code.
But it is not working.
can you please help me to solve this? I'm new to mysql and i'm still learning about this.

Comment: And also I need to calculate the total distance and total duration and put that values to 
values to the text boxes (txtdistance and txtduration) in the html form.

Comment: Can you please help me to slove these problems?

Comment: @aishy, I'm in deadline now and don't clearly understand yout work. I suggest you to open the new question on SO with detailed expanation and parallely hone your own skills.